# Arm v8 elf to mach-o

Tags: elf, ios7.1, mach-o

I have a program in C and Arm v8 assembly(inline assembly). I've compiled it to produce a 64 bit arm statically linked elf. I need to be able to run this on an iPhone, but its giving me an error 'Cannot execute binary file'. This is because I'm trying to run an elf and not a mach-o which is needed for the iPhone.

Is there any converter which can convert an arm v8 elf to mach-o?
Most of what I've seen are from x86 elf to mach-o

Comment: you don't convert the ELF file to Mach-O. You take an iOS assembler and translate your assembly source with that.

Comment: @user3477950 But my code is in inline assembly. Which is in a .c file

Comment: then you use `clang -arch=armv7` on your Mac to compile your C program into an iOS-compatible object file.

Comment: Thanks @user3477950. Do you of any way I can assemble an obj file to a mach-o? I have disassembled the arm v8 elf.

Comment: as I already mentioned, using the assembler which comes with the iOS toolchain.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not very familiar with iOS programming. When you say iOS toolchain, do you mean XCode? How and where do I find the assembler?

Comment: Please google "toolchain".

Answer (score 1):

You should instead consider setting up your tool-chain, compiler as well as linker correctly. You need a cross-toolchain for that target exactly.
If you were using GNU tools consider this:
Recompile your cross-compiler as well as bin-utils with a configure command with the proper target option (GNU-triplet).
For iPhone this should be: ../configure --target=arm64-apple-darwin  . . . . a.s.on
(RTFM about setting up a cross-compiler toolchain.)
Hope that helps. In any case the correct GNU-triplet will determine also the file-header.